# Which setting makes Vim flash the matching bracket/brace?

Tags: vim

The Scala plugins for Vim is flashing the matching bracket/brace for a few seconds, and then it stops the highlight. Is there a special setting I can enable in my Vim to achieve the same for all files, not only Scala ones?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for the `showmatch` option.

Related settings are:

- `showmatch`
- `matchpairs`
- `matchtime`